# ASP.NET MVC 2: Manually create a list and attach to model

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I have a model:

```
[Required]
public List<SelectList> Meals { get; set;
```

}

And I want to create a list in my Controller so I can attach it to "Meals" in my Model.

For some reason I'm having issues doing this:

```
_model.MaxCoupons = new List<SelectListItem>();
SelectListItem _mList = new SelectListItem([]{
    new SelectListItem { Text = "---", Value = "" },
    new SelectListItem { Text = "50", Value = "50" },
    new SelectListItem { Text = "60", Value = "60" },
    new SelectListItem { Text = "70", Value = "70" },
    new SelectListItem { Text = "80", Value = "80" },
    new SelectListItem { Text = "90", Value = "90" },
    new SelectListItem { Text = "100", Value = "100" },
    new SelectListItem { Text = "110", Value = "110" },
    new SelectListItem { Text = "120", Value = "120" },
    new SelectListItem { Text = "130", Value = "130" },
    new SelectListItem { Text = "140", Value = "140" },
    new SelectListItem { Text = "150", Value = "130" } },
     "Text", "Value" );
_model.MaxCoupons.Add(_mList);
```

I'm a bit confused right now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public SelectList Meals { get; set; }

public SelectList MySelectList()
{
  List<SelectListItem> _returnList = new List<SelectListItem>();

  SelectListItem _mList = new SelectListItem();
  _mList = new SelectListItem(){ Text = "---", Value = "" };
  _returnList.Add(_mList);

  //keep repeating
}
```

then inside a method:

```
Meals = new MySelectList();
```

Comment: Can I not just create a SelectList and attach it to my Model from the controller? I'm not following this... where does this go?